# Are there any online literary magazines that provide feedback regarding work that they turn down?

Tags: creative-writing, magazines

I’ve gotten sick and tired of being rejected by form emails.

At this point, I prefer to only send to magazines who will at least give a bit of feedback to authors whose work they turn down.

**Do you know magazines/editors who routinely make comments about the story in their rejection emails?**

Comment: Have you tried small, unknown magazines who aren't receiving dozens of submissions every day, and so are *able* to find the time to provide feedback?  Or, perhaps, hiring a professional editor to review and feed-back on several pieces of your work, to get an honest opinion (however brutal it may be) rather than expecting these magazines to provide you with such a service for free?

Comment: I ask because I have heard that there are several magazines/editors that DO provide free feedback.

Comment: Also, why does that mean you should downvote my question? I have seen questions asked here before regarding magazines or editors and their behavior and policies. So why can't i also ask?

Comment: @user394536 You can't know that Chronocidal was the one who downvoted your question. I don't see any suggestion from him that your question is off-topic, either, and nobody has voted to close it so far. Downvotes and close-votes are not the same thing.

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but things that might be the problem: "pretentious"; "will at least have the kindness"; obliviousness to the fact that editors get a huge number of submissions and usually don't have time to respond personally to each one; general tone of entitlement.

Answer (score 2):

Most magazines are understaffed, and the staffers they have are overworked --print media is a difficult career, these days. Combine that with the ease of submitting work via email, and you reach a situation where **most editors are overwhelmed with submissions**, which makes responding personally to them difficult. In addition, there are very few advantages and some significant disadvantages to providing actual feedback. For one, many writers --myself being one --get emotionally invested in their work, and can take negative criticism badly. Conversely, encouraging criticism might unleash a flood of follow-ups. Keep in mind, providing feedback isn't really a part of their job or their mission. Given the large number of polished, accomplished writers out there, it really doesn't do a magazine any good to spend time on helping a less experienced writer improve their craft.

If you are really dedicated to the idea of submitting to outlets that will be willing and able to give feedback, **your best bet is small, obscure, local and/or niche publications** --ones that won't have thousands of other submissions competing for their attention.

Speaking as someone who once relied heavily on the submission process for feedback, it's a fool's game to look for useful criticism that way. **Join a local or online critique group, it will be much more valuable**. I signed up at Scribophile (a well-known online critique circle service) a little less than a year ago, and I've found it super-helpful. I always had a very fraught relationship with getting feedback/criticism, and this experience has really helped me embrace it.